# How to simplify osm2po's routable graph?

Tags: grass-gis, pgrouting, osm2po

I'm building a pgrouting routable network thanks to osm2po, the problem is that my network is too big. Indeed I want to create isochron and 1 node = 1 canvas circle, so I don't want too many nodes.

I managed to reduce my network with grass (v.clean) but when I do that I'm losing all my costs (and reverse_costs).

Is it another solution?

Comment: How big is your network? How much smaller do you expect it? Did you mean isochron travel distances ... sth. like a set of convex hulls or Alpha-shapes?

Comment: I want to get isochron based on travel times, but I don't want to draw a convex hulls, I'd like to draw 1 circle per node with the leaflet-maskcanvas api, like here [link](http://domoritz.de/vbb-coverage/).

I start with 234 614 nodes and I'd like to end with something like 10 000 nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure, if it's possible to reduce the number of nodes. Instead have a look at this thread: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50126/is-it-possible-to-get-the-points-used-for-the-convex-hull-in-osm2po

Comment: I don't want to use convex hulls because I want to modify my isochrons dynamically on the client side. I'll find another way then :)

Comment: Read the thread carefully. It does not deal with classical convex hulls. My example shows how to filter nodes/ways that exceed a certain distance from a given source. Using more distances should give you a reduced set of points for each isoline polygon.